# Oracle FORMS - Validar o invalidar registros

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracleforms

Estoy haciendo un FORM con una serie de columnas en GRID las cuales son

PARÁMETRO - VALOR ALFA - VALOR NÚMERO - VALOR FECHA - COMENTARIO

Parámetro y Comentario son obligatorias pero quiero que el usuario tenga que introducir al menos uno de los valores. Si introduce uno de ellos los demás se inhabilitan. Hasta ahí bien. El caso es que  al llegar a 'COMENTARIO', si no ha introducido uno de los 3 valores salta un trigger avisando, pero continúa al registro siguiente. Habría alguna forma de que volviera al primer campo de ese registro ('PARAMETRO') y no continuara al siguiente registro como si nada?

Agrego el trigger que estoy usando:

```
DISPSTD.WHEN_VALIDATE_ITEM;
DECLARE
v_alerta number;
BEGIN
IF :system.trigger_item = 'B2.VALOR_ALFA' THEN
    IF :B2.VALOR_ALFA IS NOT NULL THEN
        SET_ITEM_PROPERTY('B2.VALOR_NUMERO',ENABLED,PROPERTY_FALSE);
        SET_ITEM_PROPERTY('B2.VALOR_FECHA',ENABLED,PROPERTY_FALSE);
    END IF;
    IF :B2.VALOR_ALFA IS NULL THEN
        SET_ITEM_PROPERTY('B2.VALOR_NUMERO',ENABLED,PROPERTY_TRUE);
            SET_ITEM_PROPERTY('B2.VALOR_NUMERO',UPDATE_ALLOWED,PROPERTY_TRUE);
        SET_ITEM_PROPERTY('B2.VALOR_FECHA',ENABLED,PROPERTY_TRUE);
            SET_ITEM_PROPERTY('B2.VALOR_FECHA',UPDATE_ALLOWED,PROPERTY_TRUE);
    END IF;
END IF;
IF :system.trigger_item = 'B2.VALOR_NUMERO' THEN
IF :B2.VALOR_NUMERO IS NOT NULL THEN
        SET_ITEM_PROPERTY('B2.VALOR_ALFA',ENABLED,PROPERTY_FALSE);
        SET_ITEM_PROPERTY('B2.VALOR_FECHA',ENABLED,PROPERTY_FALSE);
    END IF;
    IF :B2.VALOR_NUMERO IS NULL THEN
        SET_ITEM_PROPERTY('B2.VALOR_ALFA',ENABLED,PROPERTY_TRUE);
            SET_ITEM_PROPERTY('B2.VALOR_ALFA',UPDATE_ALLOWED,PROPERTY_TRUE);
        SET_ITEM_PROPERTY('B2.VALOR_FECHA',ENABLED,PROPERTY_TRUE);
            SET_ITEM_PROPERTY('B2.VALOR_FECHA',UPDATE_ALLOWED,PROPERTY_TRUE);
    END IF;
END IF;
IF :system.trigger_item = 'B2.VALOR_FECHA' THEN
    IF :B2.VALOR_FECHA IS NOT NULL THEN
        SET_ITEM_PROPERTY('B2.VALOR_NUMERO',ENABLED,PROPERTY_FALSE);
        SET_ITEM_PROPERTY('B2.VALOR_ALFA',ENABLED,PROPERTY_FALSE);
    END IF;
    IF :B2.VALOR_FECHA IS NULL THEN
        SET_ITEM_PROPERTY('B2.VALOR_NUMERO',ENABLED,PROPERTY_TRUE);
            SET_ITEM_PROPERTY('B2.VALOR_NUMERO',UPDATE_ALLOWED,PROPERTY_TRUE);
        SET_ITEM_PROPERTY('B2.VALOR_ALFA',ENABLED,PROPERTY_TRUE);
            SET_ITEM_PROPERTY('B2.VALOR_ALFA',UPDATE_ALLOWED,PROPERTY_TRUE);
    END IF;
END IF;
IF :system.trigger_item = 'B2.D_PARAMETRO' THEN
        IF :B2.VALOR_ALFA IS NULL AND :B2.VALOR_NUMERO IS NULL AND :B2.VALOR_FECHA IS NULL THEN
        v_alerta := show_alert('NULL_ALERT');
        END IF;
END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

Para todo aquel que desee saber la respuesta y para que conste en registro para futuros programadores de Oracle Forms he aquí como lo he resuelto:

Primero, y antes de nada, cambiar la validación de los items. En mi pregunta había puesto un deshabilitador de campos cuando se introducía uno de ellos, pero al final resulta engorroso pues al intentar cambiarlo se "traba" y tienes que hacer click en otro campo para activar los restantes. De este modo se consigue que al escribir otro, se borre el anterior.

**WHEN-VALIDATE-ITEM**

```
DISPSTD.WHEN_VALIDATE_ITEM;
DECLARE
  v_alerta number;
BEGIN
  IF :system.trigger_item = 'B2.VALOR_ALFA' THEN
     IF :B2.VALOR_ALFA IS NOT NULL THEN
          :B2.VALOR_NUMERO := NULL;
            :B2.VALOR_FECHA := NULL;
     END IF;
  ELSIF :system.trigger_item = 'B2.VALOR_NUMERO' THEN
 IF :B2.VALOR_NUMERO IS NOT NULL THEN
        :B2.VALOR_ALFA := NULL;
        :B2.VALOR_FECHA := NULL;
     END IF;
  ELSIF :system.trigger_item = 'B2.VALOR_FECHA' THEN
     IF :B2.VALOR_FECHA IS NOT NULL THEN
        :B2.VALOR_ALFA := NULL;
        :B2.VALOR_NUMERO := NULL;
     END IF;
  END IF;
END;
```

Ahora creamos un nuevo trigger con el siguiente código:

**WHEN-VALIDATE-RECORD**

```
DISPSTD.WHEN_VALIDATE_RECORD;
DECLARE
  V_ALERTA      NUMBER;
BEGIN
  IF :B2.VALOR_ALFA IS NULL 
 AND :B2.VALOR_NUMERO IS NULL 
 AND :B2.VALOR_FECHA IS NULL THEN
 MSG.MENSAJE('RI','PARAMNUL');
     :PARAMETER.P_CONDICION := 'NO';
     :PARAMETER.P_RECORD := :SYSTEM.TRIGGER_RECORD;
  ELSE
     :PARAMETER.P_CONDICION :='SI';
  END IF;
END;
```

Evidentemente, los parámetros P_CONDICION y P_RECORD tendremos que crearlos nosotros.

Ahora, por último creamos el trigger que recogerá ese parámetro:

**WHEN-NEW-RECORD-INSTANCE**

```
DISPSTD.WHEN_NEW_RECORD_INSTANCE;
BEGIN
  IF :PARAMETER.P_CONDICION = 'NO' THEN
    GO_RECORD(:PARAMETER.P_RECORD);
  END IF;
END;
```

Espero que os resuelva el problema :)